# Retrieving user info from id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a web app and am having trouble with a trivial issue. I have a table in a database, persons, which consists of the following fields: id, position (in company), username, firstname, lastname. I am working on an edit_user page. I have a main page listing the first+last names of all the users. I can then click on the names and this takes me to the edit_user page corresponding to that user. However, the updates that I make on the website do not get sent to the database (see code below).

```
//Inserting updates into database
        $query = "UPDATE person SET
            privilege  = '{$privilege}',
            nexus = '{$nexus}',
            firstname ='{$firstname}',
            lastname = '{$lastname}'"; 
        $query .="  WHERE id={$personid}";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$connection); 
        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { 
            $message = "User was successfully updated"; 
        } else { 
            $message = "User was not updated";
            $message .= "<br/>" .mysql_error();
        }
```

My premonition is that something is wrong with the {$personid}, which was defined by:

```
function find_selected_user() {
    global $user;
    if (isset($_GET['personid'])) { 
        $personid = $_GET['personid'];
        return $personid
    } else {
        $user = NULL; 
    }
}
```

(the above function is *supposed* to return an array of $user's information)
Please help -- I am so stuck! I am sure it is so simple but I've been thinking about it too long

Comment: Can you give a var_dump() of $userid, to make sure it's actually got a value?

Comment: Instead of firing the query, try echo $query and check what query you are creating.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Why is your function not returning anything in the else part.
Also are you using global $user for userid or the returned value of this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the ending ; character here:

```
return $personid
```

Should be:

```
return $personid;
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually got an error message telling me that as well. It is fixed now but the same problem persists

Comment: I ended up re-writing the page. It works now (I think!). Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Can you echo the complete `$query` variable to the screen or save it in a log?

Copy this output and try to use mysql command line or phpmyadmin to test the sql query.

Or maybe `echo mysql_error();` to see if there is an error being reported.

Maybe your `{$personid}` variable isn't being populated how you think it is.

Comment: Hi, that is a good suggestion but I am not sure how to execute it (sorry, very new to this). Do you mean simply add an "echo $query;" statment directly under my query? I tried that but nothing is being echoed to the web. (In further detail: I click on desired user to edit -> takes me to edit_user(with correct address, example: ends with edit_user.php?user=4) --> I type in my edits --> takes me to a new blank edit_user page, no updates occured on phpmyadmin)

Comment: yes echo $query should display it to screen. Maybe it is not working for you because the html code around it is in a table or the output is covered by a absolutely position div. Is your script redirecting before displaying to screen. If you can see what is outputted on the $message variable maybe add the $query to that.
$message .= $query;

Comment: I ended up re-writing the entire thing, and it does work now. But thank you, I'll keep that in mind when I am debugging in the future